# ember.js: keep sidebar with a list of items while I'm creating or editing a record

Tags: ember.js

Basically, I want a simple structure: a sidebar (with a list of games), and forms in the center (new/edit).

So, when user access the route route /games/new, it'll render the new form in the center, and keep the sidebar in left. When user access /games/1/edit, it'll render de edition form in the center, keep sidebar in the left and select the item that is being edited.

My problem is about the sidebar. I didn't find a way to solve this, I think that I need to use 2 distinct controllers, but I don't know...

http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrebini/8BKE8/19/

Answer (score 2):

You should create a controller to render the games in the sidebar, `GamesController`. You can connect the sidebar outlet with the `GamesController` and the collection of games in the `games` route (parent of both `new` and `edit`). In the `edit` route, you can set a `selectedObject` property of the `GamesController` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is Sidebar has the list of games, each element in the list has "name of Game", "edit" button...On the top of sidebar will be the plus button which on click will allow you to add a new game, once a new game is created it'll be added to the list of games which will have the "edit" button...We can accomplish this pretty neatly using Ember.CollectionView, will post the fiddle when I get some spare time , asap ! 

**PS: you don't need many controllers I think, only one which will execute based on the context selected(selected game).**